Piece values derived computationally
I've read that pieces in chess have values, I think it was the book Chess in a Nutshell, from my childhood. For example, see What is the origin/history of the traditional piece values?. Has computer evaluation determined piece values more precisely. For example, they may not be integer multiples of each other. I am also aware that these values would in a more complicated sense be also functions of their positions and the given board layout. Are there published sets of heuristics that are computationally derived? Also, I am very inexperienced, so if this question is missing anything, please correct it.

https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/what-relative-point-values-of-pieces-do-engines-use Does this answer your question?

@Allure Yes, that's it. Also, what about other rules from engines that humans can use?

I suppose one could memorize the piece square tables (https://www.chessprogramming.org/Piece-Square_Tables), but it's not very helpful, which is why it's not commonly done.
